# Using AWK compare two files having single columns in each and get count againts each matched item

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I am going to split my problem as two problems

### Problem 1

I have two numerically sorted files having single column as below. File t1.txt has unique values. File t2.txt has duplicate values.

file1: t1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

file2: t2.txt
    0
    2
    2
    3
    4
    7
    8
    9
    9

The output I require is as below:
item matched ---> times it matched in t2.txt

With awk I am using this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' t2.txt t1.txt
```

The output I get is:

```
2
3
4
```

However I want this:

```
2 --> 2
3 --> 1
4 --> 1
```

### Problem 2

I am going to run this on large files. The actual target files have below line count:

```
t1.txt 9702304
t2.txt 32412065
```

How can we enhance the performance of the script/solution as the file size increases. Please consider that both files will have exactly one column and will be numerically sorted.

Will appreciate your help here. Thanks!

Comment: For the second case, do a `uniq -c` after sorting and use the counts when matching the field.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use awk, this pipeline gets you most of the way there:

```
$ grep  -Fxf t1.txt t2.txt | sort | uniq -c
      2 2
      1 3
      1 4
```

Comment: If, as you say in problem 2, the files are already sorted, remove `sort` from the pipeline

Comment: Performance comparison:
t1.txt --> 3287200 lines
t2.txt --> 15870428 lines
@glenn jackman: took 29 secs
Thanks for your prompt help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
$ join <(sort t1.txt) <(sort t2.txt) | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " --> " $1}'
2 --> 2
3 --> 1
4 --> 1
```

(Of course you can skip the sort if the files are really already sorted, though I noticed in your sample data that `0` follows `9`.)

Comment: Performance comparison:
t1.txt --> 3287200 lines
t2.txt --> 15870428 lines
@jas: took 12 secs
Thanks for your prompt help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For your problem1, this one-liner should help.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{b[$1]++}END{for(x in b)printf "%s --> %s\n", x, b[x]}' f1 f2
```

tested with your data:

```
kent$  head f*

==> f1 <==
1
2
3
4
5

==> f2 <==
2
3
4
2
7
8
9
9
0

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{b[$1]++}END{for(x in b)printf "%s --> %s\n", x, b[x]}' f1 f2
2 --> 2
3 --> 1
4 --> 1
```

For the problem 2, you can test this one-liner on your files, see if performance is ok.

Comment: I did not try your solution but thanks for your prompt help. Much appreciated

Comment: @vsingh it's ok. can you pls test the line with your two files? I want to know how fast/slow the awk oneliner is.